# How to solve caveats of ast.unparse?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to modify some constructs of python source code (e.g. variable names). Working with plain python is troublesome, so I am using abstract syntax trees. Using `ast` (built-in python library) worked out great for me, but in docs of `ast.unparse()` there are two warnings that I'm concerned about, since I don't want any uncontrolled modifications.

```
# small example 
import ast

code = 'a = 0'
root = ast.parse(code)

for node in ast.walk(root):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Name):
        node.id = 'b'

code = ast.unparse(root)
print(code)
```

[image]

How to unparse `ast` without running into these problems?

Are there any alternatives to this method?

Comment: Although you will have to work a bit to preserve some semblance of the original formatting, it is considered unfriendly to use images of text here. Images are hard to read on many devices (screen-readers, in particular), and do not allow copy and paste of contents, which is often useful in answers. Also, you should always cite your quotes; otherwise, it's plagiarism (even when its reasonably obvious what the source is). Please edit your question to include a link to the original material. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the line about compiler optimizations is referring to, but basically the AST does not include comments and indentation has been reduced to `INDENT` and `DEDENT`, while other whitespace has been removed altogether. `unparse` treats an indent as being exactly four spaces, and inserts a single space character between tokens if necessary. That indeed might be a problem if you are attempting to edit existing code.

If you want to preserve comments and whitespace, you'll have to use a different parsing strategy, not based on the built-in AST model. There are parsers which preserve comments and whitespace (for example, parsers used for syntax highlighting); if you feel you need one, you should be able to find one with an internet search.

As for the recursion depth warning, you'll need extremely deeply nested code to trigger a stack overflow. Practically no-one writes code by hand which would trigger the problem, but it certainly can happen. Mostly it happens on machine-generated code. Personally, I wouldn't worry about it until it happens to you, since there's a good chance that it will never happen in your problem domain. (And, if it does happen, you'll be informed because it raises an exception, rather than diving into Undefined Behaviour like Certain other programming languages.)